# Error building Go with gRPC Docker container

Tags: docker, go, containers, grpc

I am trying to turn my golang grpc application into a docker container, however i keep getting an error when trying to build.

The error is

```
 messagepb/stickynote.pb.go:16:8: cannot find package "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto (from $GOROOT)
        /go/src/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto (from $GOPATH)
sticky.go:6:2: cannot find package "github.com/llgcode/draw2d" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/github.com/llgcode/draw2d (from $GOROOT)
        /go/src/github.com/llgcode/draw2d (from $GOPATH)
sticky.go:7:2: cannot find package "github.com/llgcode/draw2d/draw2dimg" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/github.com/llgcode/draw2d/draw2dimg (from $GOROOT)
        /go/src/github.com/llgcode/draw2d/draw2dimg (from $GOPATH)
messagepb/stickynote.pb.go:21:2: cannot find package "golang.org/x/net/context" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/golang.org/x/net/context (from $GOROOT)
        /go/src/golang.org/x/net/context (from $GOPATH)
messagepb/stickynote.pb.go:22:2: cannot find package "google.golang.org/grpc" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/google.golang.org/grpc (from $GOROOT)
        /go/src/google.golang.org/grpc (from $GOPATH)
main.go:7:2: cannot find package "google.golang.org/grpc/credentials" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/google.golang.org/grpc/credentials (from $GOROOT)
        /go/src/google.golang.org/grpc/credentials (from $GOPATH)
```

The Dockerfile is

```
FROM golang:latest

RUN mkdir -p /go/src/github.com/alhennessey92/mygoapp
ADD . /go/src/github.com/alhennessey92/mygoapp

WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/alhennessey92/mygoapp
EXPOSE 8080

RUN go install github.com/alhennessey92/mygoapp
ENTRYPOINT ["/go/bin/mygoapp"]
```

The file structure is as follows

```
go
-- src
---- github.com
------ alhennessey92
-------- mygoapp
---------- Dockerfile
---------- main.go
---------- sticky.go
---------- messagepb
------------ stickynote.pb.go
------------ stickynote.proto
```

This is the code for main.go

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "net"
    "log"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/credentials"
    "golang.org/x/net/context"
    pb "github.com/alhennessey92/mygoapp/messagepb"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
)


const (
    useSSL = false
)

type StickyNoteServer struct{}

var stickyNoteServer StickyNoteServer



func (s *StickyNoteServer) Get(ctx context.Context, r *pb.StickyNoteRequest) (*pb.StickyNoteResponse, error) {
    var sticky Sticky
    sticky.Message = r.Message
    sticky.Centered = false

    resp := &pb.StickyNoteResponse{}
    stickyBytes, err := sticky.DrawPNG(512, 512)
    resp.Image = *stickyBytes

    return resp, err
}
func (s *StickyNoteServer) Update(stream pb.StickyNote_UpdateServer) error {
    for {
        in, err := stream.Recv()
        if err == io.EOF {
            return nil
        }
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        var sticky Sticky
        sticky.Message = in.Message
        sticky.Centered = false

        resp := &pb.StickyNoteResponse{}
        stickyBytes, err := sticky.DrawPNG(512, 512)
        resp.Image = *stickyBytes

        if err := stream.Send(resp); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}

 //[START main]
func main() {


    var err error
    var lis net.Listener
    var grpcServer *grpc.Server
    if !useSSL {
        lis, err = net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
        }
        grpcServer = grpc.NewServer()
    } else {
        certFile := "ssl.crt"
        keyFile := "ssl.key"
        creds, err := credentials.NewServerTLSFromFile(certFile, keyFile)
        lis, err = net.Listen("tcp", ":443")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
        }
        grpcServer = grpc.NewServer(grpc.Creds(creds))
    }
    pb.RegisterStickyNoteServer(grpcServer, &stickyNoteServer)
    grpcServer.Serve(lis)
}
```

This is the code i am running in the terminal to build the docker container

```
docker build -t alhennessey92/mygoapptest .
```

The go code i am using is from the google cloud grpc demo stickynote - https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-compute-engine-grpc

I think the error has something to do with using the command `go get`, however i am not sure

Thanks for your help

Comment: I think you need a `-p` on your mkdir command. `RUN mkdir -p /go/src/github.com/alhennessey92/mygoapp`

Comment: Hi, just tried that but getting the error `can't load package: package /go/src/github.com/alhennessey92/mygoapp: import "/go/src/github.com/alhennessey92/mygoapp": cannot import absolute path`

Comment: Different error, different problem. I think that one points to your install line needing to use a relative path: `RUN go install github.com/alhennessey92/mygoapp`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i have implemented what you said, but now getting a different set of errors, i have edited the question with the updated code and errors

Comment: @AlHennessey: Now it appears you haven't installed any of your dependencies. You haven't run `go get`; are you expecting them to be vendored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to add `go get` to your docker file, or you need to [vendor](https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2015/vendor-folder/) the third party libraries with a tool like [dep](https://github.com/golang/dep).

vendoring is better, but if you want to just download files in docker container, do:

```
FROM golang:latest

RUN mkdir -p /go/src/github.com/alhennessey92/mygoapp
ADD . /go/src/github.com/alhennessey92/mygoapp

WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/alhennessey92/mygoapp
EXPOSE 8080

RUN go get ./...
RUN go install 
ENTRYPOINT ["/go/bin/mygoapp"]
```

Answer (score 0):

i faced similar problem as yours

turns out i was not creating folder correctly
i was missing these lines from docker file

```
 ADD . /go/src/github.com/grpc/app_folder_name
 WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/grpc/app_folder_name`
```

this is my dockerfile

```
FROM golang
# Copy our file in the host contianer to our contianer
ADD . /go/src/github.com/grpc/app_folder_name
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/grpc/app_folder_name
RUN go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go
RUN go get -u google.golang.org/grpc
RUN go get -u go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo
RUN go get -u github.com/go-redis/redis
RUN go install -v ./...
# Generate binary file from our /app
RUN go build /go/src/github.com/grpc/app_folder_name/app_server/app.go
# Expose the ports used in server
EXPOSE 50051:50051
EXPOSE 27018:27018
# Run the app binarry file 
CMD ["./app"]
```

`